# how to insert a score counter in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def quiz(demand,correct):
    print(" ")
    Score=0
    Answer=input(demand)
    Answer=Answer.lower()
    if Answer!="y" and Answer!="n":
        print("I did not understand the answer")
        quiz(demand,correct)
    elif Answer==correct:
        print("correct answer")
        Score=Score+1
        return Score
    else:
        print("wrong answer")
demand1="the Napoleon's horse is white? y/n: "
correct1="y"
quiz(demand1,correct1)
demand2="berlusconi is president of italy? y/n: "
correct2="n"
quiz(demand2,correct2)
print("score:",Score)
```

*I'm trying to insert a score counter,
 why does not it work?
 can someone give me the solution?
 I'm sorry for my bad english.*

Comment: `score` needs to be outside of `quiz`

Comment: `Can someone give me the solution?` is, unfortunately, not how SO works. In this case, go through your logic line by line and tell us where you get stuck. We are more likely to be able to help you this way, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function and assign the value to a variable and print. Note that the variable scope is local to a function and calling it from outside requires some special declaration `global`.

```
Score = 0
def quiz(demand,correct):
    global Score
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is scope, `score` gets set to zero every time you call `quiz`
The quickest solution is as follows

```
Score=0
def quiz(demand,correct):
    print(" ")
<everything else is the same>
```